# Unsuppress UnicodeEncodeError exceptions when run from Aptana Studio PyDev

Tags: python, django, unicode, python-unicode

The following is a statement that should raise an `UnicodeEncodeError` exception:

```
print 'str+{}'.format(u'unicode:\u2019')
```

In a Python shell, the exception is raised as expected:

```
>>> print 'str+{}'.format(u'unicode:\u2019')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    print 'str+{}'.format(u'unicode:\u2019')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)
```

However, if I place that line at the start of my `settings.py` and start the Django server from Aptana Studio, no error is raised and this line is printed:

```
str+unicode:’
```

But if I execute `manage.py runserver` from a shell, the exception is raised:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is there some sort of Python setting that silently suppresses these unicode errors?

How can I prevent the unicode error from being ignored when I start the Django test server directly from Aptana Studio?

Using

- Python 2.7.3
- Aptana Studio 3.3.2

Comment: Does Aptana studio maybe mess with your interpreter's default encoding? What does `import sys; print sys.getdefaultencoding()` say if you run it from within Aptana?

Comment: @LukasGraf Ah, this might be it... Aptana Studio says: `UTF-8`. From the console it says: `ascii`. How do I change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply cast a bytestring to unicode, like

```
print unicode(s)
```

or mix unicode and bytestrings in string formatting operations like your example, Python will fall back on the system default encoding (which is `ascii` unless it has been changed), and implicitly will try to encode unicode / decode the bytestring using the `ascii` codec.

The currently active system default encoding can be displayed with

```
import sys
sys.getdefaultencoding()
```

Now it seems like Aptana Studio does in fact mess with your interpreters default encoding:

From a [blog post by Mikko Ohtamaa](http://opensourcehacker.com/2010/01/24/aptana-studio-eclipse-pydev-default-unicode-encoding/):

> [...] Looks like the culprint was PyDev (Eclipse Python plug-in). The
>   interfering source code is
>   [here](http://github.com/aptana/Pydev/blob/master/plugins/org.python.pydev/PySrc/pydev_sitecustomize/sitecustomize.py).
>   Looks like the reason was to co-operate with Eclipse console. However
>   it has been done incorrectly. Instead of setting the console encoding,
>   the encoding is set to whole Python run-time environment, messing up
>   the target run-time where the development is being done.
>
> There is a possible fix for this problem. In **Eclipse Run…** dialog settings you can choose **Console Encoding** on **Common** tab. There
>   is a possible value US-ASCII. I am not sure what Python 2 thinks
>   “US-ASCII” encoding name, since the default is “**ascii**”.

So make sure you reset the default to `ascii`, and you should be good.

Comment: Wow that blog hit my problem right on... Production unicode problem whereas I can't reproduce it from dev until I figured out the cause... And now this fix works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help you get your errors back :-)