# JSON in Python: encoding issue on OS X, no issue on Windows

Tags: python, json, windows, macos, encoding

I have a file `log.json` that contains one line:

```
{"k":"caf\u00e9"}
```

I run the following code on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate:

```
import json 
a = json.load(open('log.json', 'r'))
f = open('test.txt', 'w')
f.write(a['k'])
```

I don't have any issue.

When I run the same code on Max OS X 10.10 x64:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/francky/Documents/workspace/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    f.write(a['k'])
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How comes it works fine on Windows but not on OS X?

---

The versions of the Python interpreter as well as of the JSON Python package are the same on the two OS:

```
import json 
import sys
print json.__version__
print(sys.version)
```

returns on OS X:

```
2.0.9
2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)]
```

and on Windows:

```
2.0.9
2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:24) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

---

The culprit was PyDev, which [used to use the Eclipse workspace or project setting "Text file encoding" and sets this as the Python default encoding](https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev/315) (fixed in PyDev 3.4.0 and after).

and to support some non-ASCII characted I had switched Python file to UTF-8:

[image]

which caused Python's `sys.getdefaultencoding()` to be `UTF-8`:

[image]

FYI: [Dangers of sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28657010/395857)

Comment: what do you get when you type print(sys.getdefaultencoding())?  Probably on os x it's the default 'ascii', but not sure what it would be for windows that it is working

Comment: afaik, os x is doing the "right" thing; it's throwing up because you've asked to write unicode that cannot be encoded with the ascii codec to disk (it uses the system default codec when you do not specify an encoding)... you want to be using something like `f.write(a['k'].encode('utf8'))`

Comment: @lemonhead Thanks, `print(sys.getdefaultencoding())` outputs `ascii` on both computers. Indeed `.encode('utf8')` solves the issue, but any idea why Windows is fine with it?

Comment: hmm, yeah not sure but this section may elucidate things: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#unicode-filenames

Comment: hmm looks like my Eclipse on Windows is modifying `sys.getdefaultencoding()` to `UTF-8` (unlike the Eclipse on Mac). I had run `print(sys.getdefaultencoding())` outside Eclipse, which was a bad idea. Mystery solved, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get your OSX failure on Windows, and it *should* fail because writing a Unicode string to a file requires an encoding.  When you write Unicode strings to a file Python 2 will implicitly convert it to a byte string using the default `ascii` codec and fails for non-ASCII characters.  Are you sure you are running Python 2.7?  Python 3 gives no error.  `io.open` is the Python 3 equivalent of `open` on Python 2 and defaults to using `sys.getfilesystemencoding()`.  Here's how to fix Python 2:

```
import json
import io
data = r'{"k":"caf\u00e9"}'
a = json.loads(data)
with io.open('test.txt','w') as f:
    f.write(a['k'])
```

You can optionally specify the exact encoding you want for the output as an additional parameter:

```
with io.open('test.txt','w',encoding='utf8') as f:
```

Comment: Thanks, yes sure I'm on Python 2.7.

Comment: I'm running Windows 7 SP1 x64 also...and it *should* fail.  There's something different about your setup...

Comment: hmm looks like my Eclipse on Windows is modifying `sys.getdefaultencoding()` to `UTF-8` (unlike the Eclipse on Mac). Mystery solved, thanks!

Comment: I'd call that a bug.  Changing the default encoding can break modules that assume the default doesn't change.  It's not recommended.  Python even disables `sys.setdefaultencoding()`.

Comment: And to make things worse: [PyDev used to use the Eclipse workspace or project setting "Text file encoding" and sets this as the Python default encoding.](https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev/315)... My PyDev version (3.0.0) is affected by this issue.