# What happens when encode is used on str in python?

Tags: python, string, unicode, encode, python-2.x

I got the point about unicode, encoding and decoding. But I don't understand why the encode function works on str type. I expected it to work only on unicode type.
Therefore my question is : what is the behavior of encode when it's used on a str rather than unicode ?

Comment: What do you think happens to unicode when it is encoded and decoded?

Comment: Use Python 3 and most of the confusion will be gone.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Python 2 there are two types of codecs available; those that convert between `str` and `unicode`, and those that convert from `str` to `str`. Examples of the latter are the `base64` and `rot13` codecs.

The `str.encode()` method exists to support the latter:

```
'binary data'.encode('base64')
```

But now that it exists, people are also using it for the `unicode` -> `str` codecs; encoding can only go from `unicode` to `str` (and decoding the other way). To support these, Python will *implicitly* decode your `str` value to `unicode` first, using the ASCII codec, before finally encoding.

Incidentally, when using a `str` -> `str` codec on a `unicode` object, Python first implicitly encodes to `str` using the same ASCII codec.

In Python 3, this has been solved by a) removing the `bytes.encode()` and `str.decode()` methods (remember that `bytes` is sorta the old `str` and `str` the new `unicode`), and b) by moving the `str` -> `str` encodings to the `codecs` module *only*, using the [`codecs.encode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.encode) and [`codecs.decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.decode) functions. What codecs transform between the same type has also been clarified and updated, see the [*Python Specific Encodings* section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings); note that the 'text' encodings noted there, where available in Python 2, encode to `str` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Besides I didn't know about base64 and rot13 !

Answer (score 4):

Python realizes that it can't do an `encode` on a `str` type, so it tries to `decode` it first!  It uses the `'ascii'` codec, which will fail if you have any characters with a codepoint above 0x7f.

This is why you sometimes see a `decode` error raised when you were trying to do an `encode`.

Comment: nitpick:  it uses `sys.getdefaultencoding()` (which is almost always `'ascii'`)

Comment: @wim thanks for that, I didn't know it - I've never seen `sys.getdefaultencoding` return anything other than `'ascii'`.

Comment: @MarkRansom: that's because `sys.setdefaultencoding` is removed by `site.py`. `reload(sys)` will bring it back, but setting the default to anything but `ascii` is a [*very bad idea*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28657010/dangers-of-sys-setdefaultencodingutf-8). You often see `import sys; reload(sys); sys.setdefaultencoding(...)` cargo-culted on questions about Unicode problems.

Answer (score 3):

In Python 3, encoding a bytestring simply does not work.

```
>>> b'hi'.encode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Python 2 *tries* to be helpful when you call `encode` on a `str` and first tries to *decode* the string with `sys.getdefaultencoding()` (usually ascii) and *afterwards* encode it.

That's why you get the the rather weird error message that decoding with ascii is not possible when you try to encode with utf-8.

```
>>> 'hi\xFF'.encode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Ned explains it better than I, watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sgHbC6udIqc) from 16:20 onward.