# Tokenize a paragraph into sentence and then into words in NLTK

Tags: python, nltk

I am trying to input an entire paragraph into my word processor to be split into sentences first and then into words.

The following code I tried does not seem to work:

```py
# Text is the paragraph input
sent_text = sent_tokenize(text)
tokenized_text = word_tokenize(sent_text.split)
tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokenized_text)
print(tagged)
```

however this is not working and gives me errors. So how do I tokenize paragraphs into sentences and then words?

Here is  a paragraph I'm using (Note: it's from a public domain short story: A Dark Brown Dog by Stephen Crane)

```
This thing seemed to overpower and astonish the little dark-brown dog, and wounded him to the heart. He sank down in despair at the child's feet. When the blow was repeated, together with an admonition in childish sentences, he turned over upon his back, and held his paws in a peculiar manner. At the same time with his ears and his eyes he offered a small prayer to the child.
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of `text`?

Comment: @alvas its just any random paragraph.

Comment: Show the input, because the code will be different depending on the encoding, shape, input differences.

Comment: @alvas here is the input, so what kind of encoding, shape and input differences should be included?

Comment: Show an actual sample input... If it's just plain english text (not social media, e.g. twitter), you can easily do `[pos_tag(word_tokenize(sent)) for sent in sent_tokenize(text)]` and using Python3 should resolve most issues with utf-8. But if your input is a different encoding/format, you'll find further problems later.

Comment: @alvas I will just be copy and pasting paragraphs after paragraphs but there are still some encoding issues. If I copy paste the example text, it gives me encoding errors, why?

Comment: Upload a copy/sample of your file on dropbox or something and share it. Perhaps we may/may not be able to help.

Comment: Also, which OS are you using? If you're using linux, what is the output of `locale` on the command line?

Comment: @alvas, I am using Windows 10 and I am using Anaconda. Spyder IDE to be precise.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You probably intended to loop over `sent_text`:

```
import nltk

sent_text = nltk.sent_tokenize(text) # this gives us a list of sentences
# now loop over each sentence and tokenize it separately
for sentence in sent_text:
    tokenized_text = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
    tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokenized_text)
    print(tagged)
```

Comment: `reload(sys); sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')` is [toxic code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828723/why-should-we-not-use-sys-setdefaultencodingutf-8-in-a-py-script). And if it's `python3`, it's rather redundant. The printing itself depends on the locale set on the user's machine.

Comment: @Nikhil, do not do the `setdefaultencoding` hack. Ask a new question about the step that's giving you encoding problems, and you'll learn how to specify the file encoding when processing unicode.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28657010/dangers-of-sys-setdefaultencodingutf-8) explains why it's a very bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for the warning :-)

Comment: who knows how to save the positions of the tokens?

Answer (score 14):

Here's a shorter version. This will give you a data structure with each individual sentence, and each token within the sentence. I prefer the TweetTokenizer for messy, real world language. The sentence tokenizer is considered decent, but be careful not to lower your word case till after this step, as it may impact the accuracy of detecting the boundaries of messy text.

```
from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer, sent_tokenize

tokenizer_words = TweetTokenizer()
tokens_sentences = [tokenizer_words.tokenize(t) for t in 
nltk.sent_tokenize(input_text)]
print(tokens_sentences)
```

Here's what the output looks like, which I cleaned up so the structure stands out:

```
[
['This', 'thing', 'seemed', 'to', 'overpower', 'and', 'astonish', 'the', 'little', 'dark-brown', 'dog', ',', 'and', 'wounded', 'him', 'to', 'the', 'heart', '.'], 
['He', 'sank', 'down', 'in', 'despair', 'at', 'the', "child's", 'feet', '.'], 
['When', 'the', 'blow', 'was', 'repeated', ',', 'together', 'with', 'an', 'admonition', 'in', 'childish', 'sentences', ',', 'he', 'turned', 'over', 'upon', 'his', 'back', ',', 'and', 'held', 'his', 'paws', 'in', 'a', 'peculiar', 'manner', '.'], 
['At', 'the', 'same', 'time', 'with', 'his', 'ears', 'and', 'his', 'eyes', 'he', 'offered', 'a', 'small', 'prayer', 'to', 'the', 'child', '.']
]
```

Comment: Thanks for giving info about the TweetTokenizer!

Answer (score 5):

```
import nltk  

textsample ="This thing seemed to overpower and astonish the little dark-brown dog, and wounded him to the heart. He sank down in despair at the child's feet. When the blow was repeated, together with an admonition in childish sentences, he turned over upon his back, and held his paws in a peculiar manner. At the same time with his ears and his eyes he offered a small prayer to the child."  

sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(textsample)  
words = nltk.word_tokenize(textsample)  
sentences 
[w for w in words if w.isalpha()]
```

> The last line above will ensure only words are in the output and not special characters
> The sentence output is as below

```
['This thing seemed to overpower and astonish the little dark-brown dog, and wounded him to the heart.',
 "He sank down in despair at the child's feet.",
 'When the blow was repeated, together with an admonition in childish sentences, he turned over upon his back, and held his paws in a peculiar manner.',
 'At the same time with his ears and his eyes he offered a small prayer to the child.']
```

> The words output is as below after removing special characters

```
['This',
 'thing',
 'seemed',
 'to',
 'overpower',
 'and',
 'astonish',
 'the',
 'little',
 'dog',
 'and',
 'wounded',
 'him',
 'to',
 'the',
 'heart',
 'He',
 'sank',
 'down',
 'in',
 'despair',
 'at',
 'the',
 'child',
 'feet',
 'When',
 'the',
 'blow',
 'was',
 'repeated',
 'together',
 'with',
 'an',
 'admonition',
 'in',
 'childish',
 'sentences',
 'he',
 'turned',
 'over',
 'upon',
 'his',
 'back',
 'and',
 'held',
 'his',
 'paws',
 'in',
 'a',
 'peculiar',
 'manner',
 'At',
 'the',
 'same',
 'time',
 'with',
 'his',
 'ears',
 'and',
 'his',
 'eyes',
 'he',
 'offered',
 'a',
 'small',
 'prayer',
 'to',
 'the',
 'child']
```