# How to extract dot(.) ended sentence?

Tags: regex

I need to extract sentence ends with dot `'.'`, but don't extract sentence ends in `' ...'` (blank and three dots).

Example:

```
I love you.
I love you too ...
```

I want to match first sentence not second.

i image python style pseudo code:

```
for string in strings:
    checker1 = (string == .)
    if checker:
        checekr2 = (prev_string(string) != blank)
        if checker2:
            extract_all_strings()
        else:
            pass
    else:
        pass
```

but I can't image regular expression code.

Comment: regex101.com is a wonderful tool: https://regex101.com/r/PmoiR6/1

Comment: or using [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/h3WCpONxmX)?

Comment: It looks like you are using Python to split text into sentences. Use NLTK. See [Tokenize a paragraph into sentence and then into words in NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37605851/3832970).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
[\w ]+\.(?!\.)
```

It matches one or more either `Word` character or `Space`, then it use a neagative look ahead to make sure there's only one dot.

Comment: thank you for your kind answer. it's really fantastic solution in my case. in fact, I should consider this pattern surrounded by other sentences. your solution is perfect!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `(?<! \.\.)\.$`, see the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/PmoiR6/1).

Comment: I have to extract all sentence when pattern is matched. your solution is only extract dot(.) but your answer give me insight of regex. thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a very simple Regex:

```
[\w ]+\.$
```

Test the solution on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/3btmkQ/2).

- `[\w ]` is a group of allowed characters, where `\w` stands for any character from `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and  stands for space itself.
- `[\w ]+` where `+` means that there the characters from the group described in the point above might appear between one and unlimited times.
- `\.` is the dot itself which must be escaped, otherwise the dot `.` matches any character.
- `$` stands for the end of a string.

This together assures that only a sentence ending with exactly one dot will be caught.

Another and less strict approach might be allow anything, where the 2nd character from the end is not a dot and the last one is a dot ([Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tekeDt/1)).

```
.+[^\.]\.$
```

Comment: thank you for your detail answer. your answer has given me a better understanding of regular expression. really appreciate