# Python regular expression matching full sentence including key word without breaking on periods that do not end a sentence (.com, U.S., etc.)

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to create a regex that will match a full sentence that includes a keyword. This is an example passage:

"Cash taxes paid, net of refunds, were $412 million 2016. The U.S. Tax Act imposed a mandatory one-time tax on accumulated earnings of foreign subsidiaries and changed how foreign earnings are subject to U.S. tax."

I want to match full sentences that include the keyword "subsidiaries". To accomplish this, I have been using the following regular expression:

```
[^.]*?subsidiaries[^.]*\.
```

However, this will only match " Tax Act imposed a mandatory one-time tax on accumulated earnings of foreign subsidiaries and changed how foreign earnings are subject to U" since the expression begins and ends at the "." in "U.S.". Is there a way to specify in the expression that I do not want it to stop at specific phrases, such as "U.S." or ".com"?

Comment: Yes. Do you have a certain list? Note that there are better ways. E.g., use NLTK to split text into sentences and then just filter out those you need.

Comment: I am trying to pull sentences from 10-K documents that is currently one long string but can easily be reformatted into a list.

Comment: BTW, are you only looking for affirmative sentences, or are interrogatory and exclamatory sentences are also in play? If yes, NLTK is the solution.

Comment: Please check my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [tokenizing the text into sentences with NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37605710/), and then check if a string is present in each item or not.

```
import nltk, re
text = "Cash taxes paid, net of refunds, were $412 million 2016. The U.S. Tax Act imposed a mandatory one-time tax on accumulated earnings of foreign subsidiaries and changed how foreign earnings are subject to U.S. tax."
sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(text)
word = "subsidiaries"
print([sent for sent in sentences if word in sent])
# => ['The U.S. Tax Act imposed a mandatory one-time tax on accumulated earnings of foreign subsidiaries and changed how foreign earnings are subject to U.S. tax.']
```

To only extract affirmative sentences (ending with `.`) add `and sent.endswith('.')` condition:

```
print([sent for sent in sentences if word in sent and sent.endswith('.')])
```

You may even check if the word you filter against is a whole word search with a regular expression:

```
print([sent for sent in sentences if re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(word), sent)])
# => ['The U.S. Tax Act imposed a mandatory one-time tax on accumulated earnings of foreign subsidiaries and changed how foreign earnings are subject to U.S. tax.']
```