# How can I extract text from string in python?

Tags: python-3.x

Say I have the code `txt = "Hello my name is bob. I really like pies."`, how would I extract each sentence individually and add the to a list. I created this messy script which gives me a number of sentences roughly in a string...

```
sentences = 0
capitals = [
    'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S',
    'T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'
]
finish_markers = [
    '.','?','!'
]
newTxt = txt.split()
for x in newTxt[1:-1]:
    for caps in capitals:
        if caps in x:
            for fin in finish_markers:
                if fin in newTxt[newTxt.index(x) - 1]:
                    sentences += 1
for caps in capitals:
    if caps in newTxt[0]:
        sentences += 1
print("Sentence count...")
print(sentences)
```

It is using the `txt` variable mentioned above. However I would now like to extract each sentence and put them into a list so the final product would look something like this...

```
['Hello my name is bob.','I really like pies.']
```

I would prefer not to use any non standard packages because I want this script to work independent of everything and offline. Thank you for any help!

Comment: Split string by `.` ? --> `"Hello my name is bob. I really like pies.".split(".") `

Comment: @Rakesh, does not always work. For ex: "This question is tagged python-3.x" - will be split into two. You might want [nltk](http://www.nltk.org/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python split text on sentences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576077/python-split-text-on-sentences)

Comment: @Austin if that can be the case then what could be the approach of identifying that this is the end of the sentence

Comment: Thank you, for now I will use the first option by @Rakesh because it is working however I will look into `nltk` but as I said I am trying to avoid using any extra packages.

Comment: @0xPrateek, see the link above.

Comment: Also could be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998629/split-string-with-multiple-delimiters-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [nltk.tokenize](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize.html)

```
import nltk
sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(txt)
```

This will give you a list of sentences.

Answer (score 0):

You could work with a regex for all the ending chars(".","?","!")and then split it into different string.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to split a string into sentences, that is a bit hard to do it with regular expressions or string functions handling. For your use case, I'd recommend a NLP library like [NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/). Then, take a look at this [Tokenize a paragraph into sentence and then into words in NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37605710/tokenize-a-paragraph-into-sentence-and-then-into-words-in-nltk).